# Raspberry PI Web server - Local connection good - outside local no connection

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, webserver, local

I don't have a ton of experience with routers or port forwarding, but I do have a new Raspberry Pi and I wanted to see if I could set up a simple Hello World page just for educational purposes. I have quite a bit set up with apache2 already installed and the web page works great on my local area network, however I can't connect to it using my LTE from my phone, telling me this thing does not connect to the internet.

I am currently using Rasbian under all the default settings from the pi.

My router is an all in one modem and router, from xfinity. After sifting through countless sites trying to solve this issue, the following 2 were the closest thing to my particular issue. My reputation is not high enough to put more than 2 links, so I will put the most important ones..

So to the best of my knowledge this is the way to do it ... 
1) Set the web server up to work locally
2) Then go into the router with the IPv4 or IPv6 (shouldn't matter which) and forward all Port 80 traffic to, say, Port 8080 where my PI 'should' be listening, then send back my web page down through Port 80 to the client calling the web page.

Under 10.0.0.1 I find this...

[image: This]

Then I go to 'Advanced'

[image: Settings]

I have tried from Start port 80 to End port 8080, which my 2 PI files I edited to listen for that port.
Those files are under

```
sudo nano /ect/apache2/sites-enabled-000-default.conf
```

and

```
sudo nano /ect/apache2/ports.conf
```

I changed

```
Listen 80
```

to

```
Listen 8080
```

and all other combinations alongside changing my router Start and End ports... none of which worked so I am lead to believe there is either a knowledge gap or I am doing something terribly wrong.

I just want to put a simply Raspberry pi web server online from my Local connection at home using a Comcast xfinity router. If anyone has any experience doing, I would seriously appreciate it, I've spent far too many hours trying to walk through this alone, so now I am reaching out to the faithful stackoverflow community.

Comment: From what IP address (LAN or WAN) are you trying to access your pi server from your phone? Make sure it is the WAN address (can be found by Googling for your IP on any computer connected to your wifi).

Comment: Run a `netstat -nl` on the Pi and see if it's listening on 0.0.0.0:80 or 127.0.0.1:80?

Comment: @JYeh --- Ahhhhh! I've been using the one under 'sudo ifconfig' then it says inet addr 10.0.0.17. So running netstat -nl gets the WAN IP? When I use my phone on wifi i can search under safari 10.0.0.17, but when I turn off wifi it simply doesn't find it. So where should I look for the WAN address?

Comment: @Will -- Thank you, I will try that too. Does that just tell me whether it's listening on the Internet's port 80 or my own LAN port 80?

Comment: I like going to a website like http://ip4.me/ and it will tell you your WAN address. the IPv4 one should be fine, IPv6 is kind of long

Comment: @JYeh --- right on, thank you so much. I will attempt that later tonight and confirm or deny whether that fixed the condition.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are almost there.

For you to be able to access your raspberry pi server from the internet, you need to find your external ip address. Your router has one external ip address that you can reach from the internet. While on your wifi, search google for "what is my ip" Google may display it as the top result, or you might have to click into a site like ipchicken. Write this IP address down.

Next, setup your router to forward all port 80 (default http port). Try setting Apache to listen on port 80, and have your router set with start port and end port to be port 80 (this makes it so you don't have to put :port-number in the address, i.e. you will do http://your-ip-address rather than http://your-ip-address:8080). The start port is the port on the external network, the end is the port that your Apache server is running on the raspi.

It looks like your raspi has the ip address of 10.0.0.17 on your local network based on your screen shot. If it doesn't, change the IP address in the port forwarding section of the router configuration to be the IP address of your pi. You can figure out what the assigned IP address of your pi is through the router interface, or by typing `ifconfig -a` and looking for the ip address of the adapter that you're using to connect to the network. Your router may have the ability to assign a static ip address to your raspberry pi while it's connected to your network. It would say something like DHCP reservation. You'd need to find the MAC address of your pi. You can do that with `ifconfig -a` as well. Then configure your modem to always assign your pi the same ip address that you've configured in the port forwarding.

Now that everything is setup, switch to your cellular connection and then try to go to the ipaddress that Google gave you.

type your-ip in browser address bar -> port 80 request to your modem's IP -> you've set external port 80 requests to be forwarded to port 80 on your internal network for the device 10.0.0.17 -> your raspberry pi will serve the HTML

Note: The external ip address of your modem is most likely not static unless you specifically pay for a static address. This address usually will stay the same for at least a day though, so if you're just testing, it's not a big problem. In the future, if you want to ensure that you'll be able to reach your pi, look into dynamic dns.

Comment: @Brian --- This is an excellent walk through. I did use DHCP reservation for the IP 10.0.0.17, but I have a feeling thats the LAN IP not the WAN IP, and quite frankly I am not sure where to find the WAN IP. I also went into 'sudo nano ect/network/interfaces' and changed my code from ip manual to ip static, from a previous tutorial I went through, so its DHCP static. So I've tried everything but that external IP address part. Is that the IP I should plug into my comcast router and search for over the net (WAN once it gets up? And should it work for LAN either way?) Thanks in advance.

Comment: first, my apologies on misspelling your name the previous comment, second, I have reserved my pis IP 10.0.0.17 under my DHCP reservation with it's cooresponding mac address. I also set up the port forward to start 80 and end 80 with IPv4 as 10.0.0.17 as you said to do previously. The IP address I get from online is: 2601:802:8005:57c4:d823:5f67:3f17:bc65, so I simply type that into my phone off LTE and it doesn't even attempt it just takes me to an error like that's not even a proper IP to type in. Not sure how to approach this.

Comment: I got it! It was hidden in another by JYeh in the site ip4.me which held my IPv4 address.

Comment: So in conclusion for any other weary soul working on this similar project. In the Comcast XFINITY router (10.0.0.1) go to Connections, find your PI, click edit, punch in the MAC Address and the LOCAL address 10.0.0.* then save, this reserves that IP on your connection. Next go to advanced, go to port forwarding, make a new port forward with HTTP as service name, TCP as type, start port 80 end port 80, and server Port IPv4 10.0.0.*, add it, go find your IPv4 address @ ip4.me, and your good. Thanks guys! I love this community. <3